# RecyclerView как сохранить и восстановить состояние скроллинга при выходе из приложения?

Tags: recyclerview, android-shared-preferences, onsaveinstancestate

Здравствуйте!
Для списка я использую `RecyclerView`, можно ли сохранить положение списка и если выйти из приложение и снова войти положение с списке была бы в том же месте.
Я нашел несколько примеров, но они не работают. Я так понял сохранить позицию нужно в `SharedPreferences`  и восстановить от туда же.

Нашел один пример, позицию сохраняет, но при выходе приложение, все теряется.
Как можно сохранить позицию в `SharedPreferences` и восстановить

```
private final String KEY_RECYCLER_STATE = "recycler_state";
private static Bundle mBundleRecyclerViewState;

    @Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    // save RecyclerView state
    mBundleRecyclerViewState = new Bundle();
    Parcelable listState = mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager().onSaveInstanceState();
    mBundleRecyclerViewState.putParcelable(KEY_RECYCLER_STATE, listState);

}

@Override
protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();

    // restore RecyclerView state
    if (mBundleRecyclerViewState != null) {
        Parcelable listState = mBundleRecyclerViewState.getParcelable(KEY_RECYCLER_STATE);
        mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager().onRestoreInstanceState(listState);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

В жизненном цикле Activity есть методы для сохранения и восстановления состояния, в которые параметром передается системный Bundle со всеми настройками. Он восстанавливается системой при старте приложения.

С точностью до замены Bundle в вашем коде. Сохранение:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // save RecyclerView state
    mBundleRecyclerViewState = savedInstanceState;
    Parcelable listState = mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager().onSaveInstanceState();
    mBundleRecyclerViewState.putParcelable(KEY_RECYCLER_STATE, listState);

   // Always call the superclass so it can save the view hierarchy state
   super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}
```

Восстановление:

```
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Always call the superclass so it can restore the view hierarchy
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

    // restore RecyclerView state
    if (mBundleRecyclerViewState != null) {
        Parcelable listState = mBundleRecyclerViewState.getParcelable(KEY_RECYCLER_STATE);
        mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager().onRestoreInstanceState(listState);
    }
}
```

Более подробную информацию по сохранению состояния см. [документацию](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html).

Comment: Но если приложение закрыть, позиция не сохраняется